# cmake error when building telegram for android

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

When I build Telegram for Android with Gradle 7.0.0-alpha5, I get an error:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users/ksash/Desktop/Telegram/TMessagesProj/-j=16" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

When I use Gradle 4.2.2, everything is OK. I use the latest stable Android Studio Arctic Fox 7.0. I have Windows 10 64 bytes. Whether it's issue, Which I should report to Google?

Comment: Sounds like a bug for Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem and I could launch the telegram successfully!

1. make sure you installed `Cmake` and `NDk` from `SDK Manager`
2. remove or  comment this line in `app/build.gradle` :

   ```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            version '3.10.2'
            arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static', '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16', "-j=16"
        }
    }
   ```
3. add this line in `app/build.gradle` in `defaultConfig` block:

   ```
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
   ```

then `Sync` and `Restart and Invalidate cache` and run the project!

happy coding :)